# Divide and Conquer C++ for duplicate array element determination

Tags: c++, arrays, divide

I have this C++ code for duplicate array element determination.
It's a correct Divide et Impera implementation?

```
    #include <iostream>

    int dupl(int a[20], int li, int ls)
    {
        if (li == ls) return ls;
        else
        {
            int x, y;
            x = dupl(a, li, (li + ls) / 2);
            y = dupl(a, (li + ls) / 2 + 1, ls);
            if (a[x] == a[x + 1])
                return x;
            else
                if (a[y] == a[y + 1])
                    return y;
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int a[20], n, i;
        std::cout << "n="; 
        std::cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        std::cin >> a[i];
        std::cout << "duplicate is: " << a[dupl(a, 0, n - 2)];
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Not all paths of your function return...

Comment: OT: it's `int main()`

Comment: Is your array `a` assumed to always be sorted ? Are there any other assumptions ?

Comment: Divide and conquer method doesn't seems appropriate for finding duplicate in array.

Comment: @Caninonos yes my array is always sorted

Comment: @Jarod42 and what method should be better to use?

Comment: C++ uses 0-indexing, not 1-indexing.

Comment: I edited with int main and with 0 indexing and now it's not working.

Comment: If array is sorted, Look at [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

Comment: @dxerok not quite `for(int i = 0; i <= n ; ++i)` iterates over n+1 elements !

Comment: OT: you don't need/usually do return 0 in main

Comment: All this problems resolved, but code don't work now. It's not showing the good duplicate.

Comment: You also forgot to initialize n (to 20 I assume). Also, why do you return a[ls] and not ls ?  what would happen is a[ls] >= n ?

Comment: @Caninonos my code should show the duplicate element that's why...

Comment: @dxerok Sure, but since you'll reuse that number as an index later (`x = dupl(a, li, (li + ls) / 2);`  then `if (a[x] == a[x + 1])`) it's very likely to cause problems. If you change that you'll have a function which find the index of a duplicate member (assuming there's one and the table is sorted). You can easily use that index to find the duplicate number. Now, that function is suboptimal (O(nlog(n)) while O(n) is enough if the table is sorted) and a bit weird, but it'd work

Comment: @Caninonos I modified now, but still no working...

Comment: @dxerok you've still forgotten to initialize `n` ! `int a[20], n, i;` should be `int a[20], n = 20, i;` ! [edit: nevermind you're actually reading it from cin, which actually is dangerous, but hey that'd work if you type 20]

Comment: @Caninonos but for example: n=5 and values are 1,2,2,3,4 the code is doesn't work or n=12 and values 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: @dxerok Ah, I missed another error. you should use dupl(a, 0, n-2) not dupl(a, 0, n-1) (think about what would happen if you called dupl(a, n-1, n-1), obviously, that also means you have to check n-2 isn't negative beforehand) and obviously print a[dupl(a, 0, n-2)] if you want the element and not the index. Now, I should really stop commenting, that comment chain has been long enough as it is !

Comment: I edited the first post but the code still not working.

Comment: You should compile with a higher warning level so that you for example see that you see that dupl does not return a value in every code path.

Comment: What index is your function supposed to return when there are no duplicates (e.g. the n=12 example you posted as a comment)? Can you imagine (with pen and paper and then follow the program in a debugger) what your function returns instead?

Comment: A linear search may provide better performance due to processor's branch prediction and cache loading algorithms.  When you divide and conquer, the values may not be in the cache, and thus the processor may have to reload the cache.  When using linear algorithm, there is a higher probability that two consecutive values are in the cache.

Comment: I guess I'll just post that here in case you still have problems: https://ideone.com/AkdBZV (that random generation don't always lead to a duplicate element although there's a pretty high chance with those parameters). I also made a mistake earlier, your function is linear, not superlinear.